# MYSQL transaction не работает из PHP

Tags: php, mysql, transaction

Делаю запрос к MYSQL вот так:

```
    mysqli_query($link, "Start transaction;
INSERT INTO `slug` (`id`, `obj`, `znach`) VALUES ('8', '222', '333');

commit;
");
```

Запросы без транзакций работают нормально. Ошибку не выводит. Если выполнить запрос через phpmyadmin - все выполняется нормально.  php-7.1  , mysql-8.0-win10.
С чем может быть связано(транзакции только начинаю курить)?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: @nazarpunk  Ответ для баллов. Или сам потом напишу. В общем для нескольких запросов нужна другая функция. Проверил работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если несколько запросов нужно отправлять из PHP вместо функции mysqli_query() нужно использовать функцию mysqli_multi_query() . Вот так:

```
 mysqli_multi_query($link, "Start transaction;
 INSERT INTO `slug` (`id`, `obj`, `znach`) VALUES ('8', '222', '333');

commit;
");
```

Answer (score 1):

Для реализации транзакций попробуйте использовать такую конструкцию, это сработает.

```
    $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8";
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, 'username', 'pass');

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2) VALUES (:col1, :col2)';

    $dbh->beginTransaction();
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $sth->bindValue(':col1', $item->id);
        $sth->bindValue(':col2', $item->name);
        $sth->execute();
    }
    $dbh->commit();
```